# Returning the first item of row value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

so i have a dataset with a row named `genres` and i want to get the first item for each entry in the database

each row in `genres` is formulated as follows: `['rock', 'pop', 'blues', 'soul', 'soul']`

I tried using `df['genres'].head(1).item())` yet this returns the very first value for `genres`, which is Rock, as the value for each column.
how can i get the first item in `genres` for each column?

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply lambda`

```
df.genres.apply(lambda x : x[0])
```

Comment: 'df['genres_adj'] = df.genres.apply(lambda x : x[0])' I tried this method, but it returned an empty row

Comment: Can i see your dataframe?

Comment: dont know how to share it here but here is a link https://github.com/scrambie/Lyricsproject